# What's desirable about callback functions when you can make a regular function call?

Tags: c#, .net, callback

I'm new to programming and I've noticed that callback functions are passed in as parameters to other functions

```
Otherfunction(argument,callbackfunction(code...code))
```

This seems cumbersome no? Why not just do the following:

```
Otherfunction(argument)
{
    callbackfunction();
}

Callbackfunction()
{
    //callback function is defined here.
}
```

Why inundate the parameter list of a function with a callback?

Comment: It would help if you'd give a *complete* example. Normally you want to decouple the callback function from the code which calls it, so that it's flexible.

Comment: Flexibility (and thus code reuse) is the most common reason for this, does that makes sense or do you have a different question?

Comment: Related pic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)#mediaviewer/File:Callback-notitle.svg

Comment: Your example is nonsensical since your second argument to `Otherfunction` is not passing in a callback function, but rather invoking it directly.  As Jon requests, please provide a *real* example that you've actually tested.  (code that is valid C# would be very helpful)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass in the callback function, then the called function needs to know which function to call. This severely limits its reuse. Passing in a callback function also allows you to modify its behavior.

Consider the following:

```
void DoSomethingAndNotify(Action<string> notifyCallback)
{
    // Do something
    ...
    string result = "something was done";

    notifyCallback(result);
}

void EmailNotifier(string message)
{
    // Send message via email
}

void ConsoleNotifier(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Then you can "do something" with different types of notifications, and you can add new notification types without ever having to change `DoSomethingAndNotify()`.